# Help Finding the Cauchy Principle Value of $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{1+2cos(\theta)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-principal-value

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{1+2cos(\theta)}$$

My attempt:

parametrise using $z=e^{i\theta}$ (i think we always use a unit circle for CPV's)

$\therefore dz = ie^{i\theta}d\theta$ $\implies d\theta=\frac{dz}{iz}$

and $2cos(\theta) = e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta} = z+z^{-1}$

we can then re-write the integral as follows:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{1+2cos(\theta)} = \displaystyle\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{(1+z+z^{-1})}\frac{dz}{iz}$$

$$\displaystyle\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{(1+z+z^{-1})}\frac{dz}{iz} = \frac{1}{i}\displaystyle\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{(z^{2}+z+1)}$$

poles are at $z^2+z+1=0$ and know that $z^2+z+1=\frac{z^3-1}{z-1}$

therefore we require that $z\ne 1$ and $z^3=1$ and we know that $z=e^{i\theta}$

$\therefore z^3=e^{\pm2ki\pi}=1 \implies z = e^{\pm 2ki\pi/3}$

now the integral can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{1}{i}\displaystyle\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{(z-e^{2ki\pi/3})(z-e^{-2ki\pi/3})}$$

i think ***CPV*** = $2\pi i\sum Residues\space at\space the\space poles$=$$2\pi i\frac{1}{i} \left( \frac{1}{e^{2ki\pi/3}-e^{-2ki\pi/3}}+\frac{1}{e^{-2ki\pi/3}-e^{2ki\pi/3}}\right) = 2\pi \left( \frac{1-1}{e^{2ki\pi/3}-e^{-2ki\pi/3}}\right)=0$$

Is what i have done here correct, is this the right way  the Cauchy integral theorem to find the CPV. Thanks for any help you can offer me.

Comment: You really should just stop at your second line and figure out which poles lie in the unit circle, and then use the residue theorem. This will give you the correct value for the real integral. I would also check the convergence of such an integral before even starting.

Comment: @DaveNine Is the CPV really just $2\pi i$(the sum of the resiudes at the singularities) and theres nothing else to it?, also why would one want to check the convergence of the integral before doing anything, whats the benefit of this? -Thank.

Comment: If the integral doesn't converge, the residue theorem won't be of very much help/ you won't be able to apply it.

Comment: Your expression $\;z^2+z+1=\frac{z^3-1}{z-1}\;$ requires, as you wrote, $\;z\neq 1\;$ ... **but** $\;z=1\;$ is one of the values on the unit circle! How will you solve this problem? BTW, *also* the other poles are on the unit circle.

Comment: Why not write $z^2+z+1 = (z-1-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)(z-1+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)$? Isn't writing $z^2+z+1=\frac{z^3-1}{z-1}$ adding extra singularities?

Comment: @Timbuc the reason i did the problem in such a weird manner is because i had something similar to this in my class notes, i had no idea that the CPV just required the residues at the singularities, i have no idea why my lecturer chose to do it in that specific way. Thanks for all your help -i really appreciate it.

Comment: @dietervdf i agree with you completely, please see post above this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is correct, but just to make sure there are no questions, I am adding a diagram of the contour and description of the method I used.

---

The Cauchy Principal Value of
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{1+2\cos(\theta)}
$$
is the contour integral
$$
\int_{\gamma^-}\frac1{1+z+z^{-1}}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{iz}
=\frac1i\int_{\gamma^-}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+z+1}
$$
where $\gamma$ is the closed contour

[image: unit circle with indentations at the singularities]

and $\gamma^-$ is $\gamma$ minus the two small arcs around the singularities at $e^{2\pi i/3}$ and $e^{4\pi i/3}$ as the radius of the arcs goes to $0$.

There are no singularities inside $\gamma$. Thus, the integral along $\gamma$ is $0$. This means that the integral along $\gamma^-$ is $\pi i$ times the sum of the residues at $e^{2\pi i/3}$ and $e^{4\pi i/3}$ (each of the small arcs is $\frac12$ a circle clockwise and we want to subtract them).

That is
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{PV}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{1+2\cos(\theta)}
&=\pi i\left[\operatorname*{Res}_{z=e^{2\pi i/3}}\left(\frac1i\frac1{z^2+z+1}\right)+\operatorname*{Res}_{z=e^{4\pi i/3}}\left(\frac1i\frac1{z^2+z+1}\right)\right]\\
&=\pi i\left[\frac{-1}{\sqrt3}+\frac1{\sqrt3}\right]\\[6pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Aren't you on the west coast?  How did I wake up too late to answer this question? (+1)

Comment: @RonGordon: I don't know. I fell asleep with the answer on my computer. I woke up and submitted it :-)

Comment: Just to clearify something, is it still fine if one uses $(z-1-\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2})(z-1+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$

Comment: @Ozwurld: if you mean $\left(z-e^{2\pi i/3}\right)\left(z-e^{-2\pi i/3}\right) =\left(z+\frac12-i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\left(z+\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)$, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{\,{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\pp\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\dd\theta \over 1 + 2\cos\pars{\theta}}}
=2\pp\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd\theta \over 1 - 2\cos\pars{\theta}}
\\[5mm]&=2\pp\int_{0}^{\infty}
{2\,\dd t/\pars{1 + t^{2}}\over 1 - 2\pars{1 - t^{2}}/\pars{1 + t^{2}}}
=4\pp\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over 3t^{2} - 1}
={4 \root{3} \over 3}\pp\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} - 1}
\\[5mm]&={4 \root{3} \over 3}\,\lim_{\epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}
\pars{\int_{0}^{1 - \epsilon}{\dd t \over t^{2} - 1}
+\int_{1 + \epsilon}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} - 1}}
\\[5mm]&={4 \root{3} \over 3}\,\lim_{\epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}
\pars{\int_{0}^{1 - \epsilon}{\dd t \over t^{2} - 1}
+\int_{1/\pars{1 + \epsilon}}^{0}{-\dd t/t^{2} \over 1/t^{2} - 1}}
\\[5mm]&={4 \root{3} \over 3}\,\lim_{\epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}
\pars{-\int_{0}^{1 - \epsilon}{\dd t \over 1 - t^{2}}
+\int_{0}^{1/\pars{1 + \epsilon}}{\dd t \over 1 - t^{2}}}
\\[5mm]&={4 \root{3} \over 3}\,\lim_{\epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}
\dsc{\int_{1 - \epsilon}^{1/\pars{1 + \epsilon}}{\dd t \over 1 - t^{2}}}
=\color{#66f}{\LARGE 0}
\end{align}

> because

\begin{align}&
0<\verts{\dsc{\int_{1 - \epsilon}^{1/\pars{1 + \epsilon}}{\dd t \over 1 - t^{2}}}}
<\int_{1 - \epsilon}^{1/\pars{1 + \epsilon}}
{\dd t \over 1 - 1/\pars{1 + \epsilon}^{2}}
={\pars{1 + \epsilon}^{2} \over \epsilon^{2} + 2\epsilon}
\bracks{{1 \over 1 + \epsilon} - \pars{1 - \epsilon}}
\\[5mm]&={\pars{1 + \epsilon}^{2} \over \pars{\epsilon + 2}\pars{\epsilon + 1}}\,
\epsilon\quad\to\quad 0\quad\mbox{when}\quad\epsilon \to 0
\end{align}